# Google API Refresh Token Security Vulnerability

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, google-api

With the introduction of [Google's new API](https://developers.google.com/products/) using OAuth 2.0 authentication, developers have the ability to set up refresh tokens which require the end user to authenticate the application only once.

The developer has the ability to [set a scope](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth) for his/her project. For a refresh-token OAuth setup, the user will only be required to approve authentication for an application once, thereafter, Google's servers will handle the re-authentication using the refresh token.

Based on the scope that the developer initially specifies, the Consent Screen will notify the user of what the application can access/modify, based on the chosen scope. Consider the following Gmail **example** on Stackoverflow:

[image]

Now, if the developer at a later stage changes the scope of the application, **the user will not have to re-approve authentication**, as the authentication was initially setup based on a refresh token, or supposed `offline access`.

The user initially approved "view your email address" access only (for example) yet now, the application could be doing **all sorts of things**, with modification access, viewing of data, contacts, etc, which **was not initially approved by the end user**

This is somewhat a security flaw / privacy breach, and there is no way for the user to identify whether an application is doing so.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior? Surely this is not ethical?

**P.S.** I've used Stackoverflow **as an example only**, I'm not accusing this website of doing so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this an actual security vulnerability that you have noticed in action, or a suspected one?

According to my references and experiences, refresh tokens are used "to retrieve additional tokens of equal or lesser scope for separate resource calls"[[1]](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/refresh-token/) For instance, after omitting a scope from my authentication flow, I received an access token which specifically refused any requests related to the omitted scope.

This suggests that changing your project's scopes after getting a user's refresh token will not allow you to access anything they have not authorized.

Comment: I have experienced this in action, with Gmail at least. Try set up an application with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly` as the scope. Create the refresh token authenticate and log in. Thereafter, modify the scope to `https://mail.google.com/` which gives "Full access to the account, including permanent deletion of threads and messages.". The user isn't queried to re-authenticate, even after 24 hours.